# Python decorator to create dictionary

Tags: python-decorators

Decorator fun!
I would like to create  a ‘function dispatch dictionary’

decorator ‘assign1’ creates a dictionary as expected:

decorator ‘assign2’  I try to make the dictionary value a tuple, things get a little weird

```
d1 = dict()
d2 = dict()
assign1 = lambda d, k: lambda f: d.setdefault(k, f)
assign2 = lambda d, k, s: lambda f: d.setdefault(k, (f,s))

@assign1 (d1, 'FW')
@assign1 (d1, 'PW')
def func1():
    pass

@assign2 (d2, 'FW', 'XX')
@assign2 (d2, 'PW', 'XD')
@assign2 (d2, 'DF', 'XC')
def func2():
    pass

print ('assign1')
for k in d1:
    print ('{0} : {1}'.format( k, d1[k]))

print('assign2')
for k in d2:
    print ('{0} : {1}'.format( k, d2[k]))


#Output
assign1
FW : <function func1 at 0x000000000311F400>
PW : <function func1 at 0x000000000311F400>
assign2
DF : (<function func2 at 0x000000000311F510>, 'XC')
FW : (((<function func2 at 0x000000000311F510>, 'XC'), 'XD'), 'XX')
PW : ((<function func2 at 0x000000000311F510>, 'XC'), 'XD')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky but here is how you could find out:

```
In [55]: func1()
In [56]: func2()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-dff3c14b0386> in <module>()
----> 1 func2()

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

What ?! `func2` is now a tuple ???

Yes it is. The [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method returns the value you have set. In the first case it worked because you set it to func1 but in the second case it became a tuple, and that tuple was applied to the next decorator and so on...